# Hiring bikes at Lago di Garda - Desenzano

Tags: italy, rental, bicycles

The next few days, my boyfried and I are going to Italy, Lago di Garda. We are going to stay at Desenzano and were wondering if anybody knew where to hire a bike there?
We'd love to experience the scenery by bike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information [here](http://www.youthpoint.eu/?page_id=2382), unfortunately in Italian.

Basically you can rent a bike for 15€ for the entire day. If you want they also provide a basic lunch for 5€.

This should be the location of the office: Piazza Einaudi 8 25015 - Desenzano del Garda Brescia Italy - +39 (030) 9142268 - desenzano@cts.it

I suppose they speak English, maybe you can call them.